# android compilation

Tags: android, compilation

I am trying to compile android source v2.3.4. When I give "make -j32", I am getting result like this.I am using fedora 14(32 bit).

```
[root@localhost WORKING_DIRECTORY]# make -j32


 ============================================


 PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL

 PLATFORM_VERSION=2.3.4

 TARGET_PRODUCT=full

 TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng

 TARGET_SIMULATOR=false

 TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release

 TARGET_BUILD_APPS=

 TARGET_ARCH=arm

 HOST_ARCH=x86

 HOST_OS=linux

 HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release

 BUILD_ID=GRJ22


 ============================================

 Checking build tools versions...

 build/core/main.mk:76: ************************************************************

 build/core/main.mk:77: You are attempting to build on a 32-bit system.

 build/core/main.mk:78: Only 64-bit build environments are supported beyond froyo/2.2.

 build/core/main.mk:79: ************************************************************

 build/core/main.mk:80: *** stop.  Stop.


 [root@localhost WORKING_DIRECTORY]#
```

Please help me to solve this issue. How to compile android source code on 32 bit os?.

Thank You
Rajendra

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. 
since version 2.3 you need 64-bit OS to build the android source code.